# Woocommerce My Account Navigation not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Logging into the Woocommerce my account page goes as planned, however when I am hovering over the vertical navigation - Woocommerce is not adding "/my-account/" to the prefix of the endpoint.

For example.

Current Link: blahblahblah.com/customer-logout/

What it should be: blahblahblah.com/my-account/customer-logout/

I tried looking into changing endpoints but i don't think that's the solution. Is it a setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you have this figured out already, but here's a helpful link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/

I ran into this same issue and was able to resolve with assigning the "My account page". It was previously blank in our instance which resulted in default links directing to /orders/ and /lost-password/ instead of /my-account/orders/ and /my-account/lost-password/.

Setting can be changed at 
WooCommerce > Settings
Accounts tab
Account pages - "My account page" is the field to edit.

Which could be found at a URL string similar to this https://www.yoururl.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=account

Screenshot: [WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts > Account pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwdw5.png)

Comment: Please include the necessary parts of the reference link in the answer

Comment: Thank you Amy, I was stuck with this issue, I have followed your answer and it worked. Thank you once again.